# How to add a calculated tax in OpenERP 7

Tags: python, odoo, invoice

I am working with OpenERP 7.

For business requirement, I have to add a tax to the invoice, this tax will be calculated like that : `tax1= amount_untaxed * 0,1 % + amount_tax * 0.1 %`

A little bit of help will be appreciated .

Comment: Are you asking where in the code you need to write that line?

Comment: I can modify the source code and add this tax to the total amount in the account_invoice.py, but I am asking if can I create this tax using the OpenERP client interface: ` accounting -> configuration -> taxes -> create`, then choose Python code as a type. If yes how can we do that ?

Comment: It seems there is a documentation about that:
https://doc.openerp.com/v6.1/book/3/3_9/tax_structure/

Comment: I don't think so. OpenERP documentation is the poorest doc

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. You can't just add the tax to the invoice total. Invoice totals are stored functional fields that are calculated as the sum of the invoice lines so you would need to adjust the tax on a specific invoice line, or add a line with the taxes.
2. Taxes are managed via fiscal positions. Create your tax object, then create a fiscal position, then add this as the default for the customer, or just apply it to an invoice on a case by case basis.

Comment: Suggestion 2 seems to be the right solution, but I am a beginner on OpenERP how can I do this ?